# Download CSV file And show Sweet alert error Message

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

I have a View With a text area(user enter all orders there ) and a Submit button ,

Once Submit button is pressed, An action method will process all the orders and save them in the Database.

If all Orders were processed successfully, I will return back to the view with an indicator (ViewBag)
that will popup a sweet alert from the javascript.

If one or more orders failed, i will download a csv file to show the failed orders.

In addition, I want to go back to the view so I can show a sweet alert error message.

I know how to download the file, and i know how to return with error message with sweet alert.

I just don't know how to do both in the same time :)

I know that i can't send 2 requests at the same time, what options do i have?

submit button Action in controller :

```
public IActionResult AddOrdersExtension(OrderVM orderVM)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
  //
   foreach(var order in ordersList)
   {
     if(isStoreAuthenticated(orderVM)) 
       _unitOfWork.Order.Add(orderVM.Orders);
       _unitOfWork.Save();
     else
     {
       failedLines = failedLines + "," + orderVM.Orders.CustName;
     }
   }
   if (failedLines.Length > 0)
   {
    ViewBag.Failed = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //
    // populate string builder with failed line
    //
    // downlaod csv file
   return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", "Error_log.csv");
  }
  else // all orders processed successfully
{
  ViewBag.Failed = false;
  return View(orderVM);
}
}
```

Java script in the view :

```
@section Scripts{
  if (ViewBag.failed)
     {
     <script>
       swal("Error Occured!", "Failed to process All Orders", "error")
                                .then((value) => {})
            </script>
    }
    else
    {
       <script>
         swal("Success!", "Orders were Processed Successfully!", "success")
                    .then((value) => { window.location.href = '/UserRole/Order'; })
       </script>
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you can't return two response at the same time, I'll solve it having a textarea with the CSV data showing the failing order, with the option to download the text into a file

You can use this Javascript function to download a file from the TextArea

```
function generateTextFile(textareaElement, filenameWithoutExtension) {
    var textToWrite = textareaElement.val();
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/csv'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = filenameWithoutExtension + ".csv";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
```